# Can I create my own DocumentPicker UI in Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I came across `DocumentPicker` from Expo and in their documentation is saying that using `DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync(options)` will `Display the system UI for choosing a document.` Now I am wondering if there is a way to handle this somehow and create my own UI for this and not showing the system UI.

I want to add more options for example DropBox or OneDrive as now I can only get files from iCloud on iOS or Google Drive on Android

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. `DocumentPicker` is a native module provided by Expo and you can't edit/add any native modules in a managed workflow, as per their [FAQ](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/):

> The most limiting thing about Expo is that you can't add in your own native modules without detaching and using ExpoKit. Continue reading the next question for a full explanation.

You can, however, detach your app and then write custom native code for it, click this [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/expokit/eject/) to see how.